# .NET: caching in database or filesystem with a CacheDependency

Tags: .net, caching

I would like to know if there is a way to have the .NET cache stored in a database table or file, rather than the in-memory cache, but also use the CacheDependency infrastructure. I think the Enterprise Library may be able to do this but I would prefer something simpler if possible.

To explain, I want the cached data to be put in an SQL table or into a file on disk, rather than in-memory. I then want to specify a CacheDependency, which could be an SqlCacheDependency, or a CacheDependency on a file or an AggregateCacheDependency.

The reason is, I do intensive calculations based on xml documents (that change once a day or so). The results of these calculations I cache in memory. However if the website is reset, the cache is lost. It would be nice to have a backup cache in the database.

Comment: you asked and deleted the same question, very recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430347/net-caching-in-database-or-filesystem-with-a-cachedependency

Comment: @cbp: I beg your pardon? I'm stating a fact.

Comment: @cbp: you voted me down with the same answer as this accepted one (to the exactly the same question), and then deleted it. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx). You'll need to manually manage the target data yourself, but you can have a dependency in the cache which is automatically invalidated when the target table changes.

**EDIT:**

Yes, you can use the Caching Block in Enterprise Library to have a cache provider that stores items in a database using the Data Access Block, which is an alternative to the ASP.NET. That's likely to be the best solution, despite the higher learning curve.

I think `SqlCacheDependency` is simpler because you use the ASP.NET cache to store a local memory version first for faster processing, falling back to the database layer when the local layer does not have the item available. Here's an example of what I mean:

- Your web application calls `GetXmlDocument(string key)` to get something to work with
- The method checks the ASP.NET cache first for the item - if the item exists, great, you return that
- If the item doesn't exist, then you check the database for the existence of the item - if the item exists, you re-populate the local cache item with a `SqlCacheDependency` on the database table, and return the XML data
- If the item doesn't exist in the database either, you retrieve the XML data from wherever the primary source is, re-populate the database, re-populate the local cache item with `SqlCacheDependency` on the table, and return the XML data

This gives you a self-managing two-tiered cache.

Comment: I already tried suggesting that in the previous same question...!

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you completely, I want the 'cache' to be a cache in the database, rather than in memory. The dependency could be anything.

Comment: @Mitch it's a conspiracy to deny you your 15 points. We're all in on it.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll investigate more into the Enterprise Library. Was just hoping to avoid it if possible.