# Store and search directory tree in memory efficiently

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to store all directories on a huge drive as efficiently in memory as possible and also be able to retrieve a directory given it's full path. Each directory has fields for it's name (not it's full path) and a  pointer to it's parent and a list of subdirectories. Which way do you think the way to go is?

As I see it there's a couple of ways:

a) Store the full paths to each directory in a dictionary and do a simple lookup. Pros: fast, Cons: each full path string takes up uneccessary and redundant amount of memory

b) Store just the actual directory name in a dictionary with a list of all directories with that name, then check the matches if it's correct: Pros: pretty fast, Cons: has to either store a list for each directory or use boxing to store either a list or directory in the dictionary.

c) Skip the dictionary, traverse the tree from the root and find a match by splitting the path. Perhaps use PLINQ to speed things up. Pros: No memory overhead with the dictionary, cons: potentially slower than lookup.

d) some other way i haven't thought of...

Comment: are you optimizing for speed/memory ?

Comment: But Why you want to do this? Is it a homework if yes please mark appropiately.

Comment: Speed before memory, but preferable not excessive memory either

Comment: Do you require online updates? Do you require directory browsing, or just look-up?

Comment: The structure might need to be rebuilt/updated/replaced once in a while but it can be fairly static in memory if that means it can be optimized, both browsing and lookup

Comment: Maybe you should look here: [.NET: caching in database or filesystem with a CacheDependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463596)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could store the subdirectories as a dictionary rather than as a list (and for cases where you want all the subdirectories, that's easily done using the `Values` property) then you can step through the path with each step being O(1) and hence the complexity of finding the directory from the full path being O(n) where n is the number of steps in the path, not related to the number of directories in the system.

Comment: I just realized that it's simple a tree traversal needed if I split the path and start from the  root that doesn't need searching every directory. Making the subdirectories into a dictionary is a good improvement though if you want to offset memory with performance.

Comment: Perhaps use  a sortedlist and binarysearch instead if one wants to optimize on memory

Comment: Yep, that makes it O(n log m) where n is the number of path steps and m the number of subdirectories in each directory (obviously will change at each step, but it gives you a measure of average case behaviour).

Comment: For a tree traversal, there might be junctions/(hard)links/symbolic links/mount points, you will have to check and exclude them

Answer (score -1):

Use a atabase. Point. Problem is the efficient search if the tree is not trivially small. It needs an index.

> Skip the dictionary, make an
>   enumerator that traverses the whole
>   tree and finds a match

Not "efficient" but the worsst possible solution time wise that is not a total waste programming wise and making things slower than a no brainer.

The problem is that efficient partial lookups require an index which is a lot of programming to maintain, compared to use something like SqlLite in the temp directory.